# Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $g: B\rightarrow C$ be invertible maps, show that $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$.

Tags: functions, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

I am working on the following problem for my abstract algebra class, and I wanted to get some feed back to see if I am on the right track. Here is what I have so far.

Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $g: B\rightarrow C$ be invertible maps, show that $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$.

$$f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}=$$
$$=(g \circ f) \circ (f \circ g)(id)$$
$$=g \circ (f \circ (f \circ g))(id)$$
$$=g(f \circ (f \circ g(id)))$$
$$=g(f(f \circ g(id)))$$
$$=g(f(f(g(id)))$$

Comment: Why don't you think about where each side maps some given element of $C$?

Answer (score 2):

1) Any proof that only contains math symbols but no English (or whatever you favourite language for human communication is) is probably insufficient.

2) Are you computing something above? perhaps you want to use some $=$ symbols somewhere.

3) Start by recalling the definition of the inverse function. Then list what you know (i.e., that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$, but spell out what that means, and similarly for $g$). Then write down what you want to prove (i.e., spell out what needs to be shown to establish that $(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$). Now try to get from what you know to what you want to know.

The proof as it currently stands is, at beast, unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h: C \rightarrow A=(g \circ f)^{-1}$. So, $(g \circ f)\circ h=1_C$.

Function composition is associative, so:
 $$g \circ(f \circ h)=1_C$$
 $$f \circ h=1_B \circ (f \circ h)=(g^{-1} \circ g)\circ(f \circ h)=g^{-1} \circ (g \circ(f \circ h))=g^{-1} \circ 1_C=g^{-1}$$
So:
$$(g \circ f)^{-1}=h=1_A \circ h = (f^{-1} \circ f) \circ h = f^{-1} \circ (f \circ h)=f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\mbox{id}= \mbox{id}\\
\mbox{id}= \mbox{id}\circ\mbox{id}\\
\mbox{id}= f^{-1}\circ f\circ\mbox{id}\\
\mbox{id}= f^{-1}\circ\mbox{id}\circ f\\
\mbox{id}= f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}\circ(g\circ f)\\
(g\circ f)^{-1}= f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}\\$$
We can conclude that
$$(g\circ f)^{-1}= f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: inequality 3 does not follow from inequality 2.

Comment: This doesn't work because composing both sides of an inequality by the same arrow could cause them to become equal. Why didn't you run this 'argument' backwards and with equalities instead of inequalities to give a perfectly good correct proof?

Comment: @DanielRust: Thanks! I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\square^{-1}=\triangle\iff\square\mathbin\circ\triangle=\mathrm{id}$. In our case show that $(g\mathbin\circ f)\mathbin\circ(f^{-1}\mathbin\circ g^{-1})=\mathrm{id}$ using that $\circ$ is associative.